# Gnuplot 5.2 errorlines With Title Ignores Line Settings (windows terminal)

Tags: gnuplot

I'm attempting to plot multiple xyerrorlines on a single Gnuplot 5.2 plot.  I've discovered xyerrorlines inherits the errorbar line properties (linewidth, dashtype) for any line that has a title specified.

Do I have a syntax issue?

The attached MWE draws two simple lines - one with a title specified, and one without.  You can see the one with notitle displays according to its own linewidth and dashtype, while the one with a title seems to inherit linewidth and dashtype from the "set errorbars" line (line 2).

```
set terminal windows color enhanced "Ariel" 8 close
set errorbars 5 linewidth 2 dashtype 1
set xrange[0:5]
set yrange[0:20]
set xlabel "X Values"
set ylabel "Y Values"

plot '-' with xyerrorlines linecolor rgbcolor "#B2B2B2" pointtype 2 pointsize 4 linewidth 4 dashtype 3 title 'Method 1',\
'-' with xyerrorlines linecolor rgbcolor "#000000" pointtype 2 pointsize 2 linewidth 4 dashtype 4 notitle
1   1   0.1 0.5
2   4   0.1 0.5
3   9   0.1 0.5
4   16  0.1 0.5
e
1   2   0.1 0.5
2   6   0.1 0.5
3   11  0.1 0.5
4   18  0.1 0.5
e
```

Which results in the following plot:
[image: Output of MWE]

Removing the line:

```
set errorbars 5 linewidth 2 dashtype 1
```

Enables independent linewidth and dashtype settings for each line with a title, but the errorbars inherit those properties, which I don't want. I want to set separate line and dash styles for the errorbars and lines (as implied in the manual, page 128.)

This behavior is duplicated in the postscript terminal as well.  I've not tested any other terminals.

I am using Gnuplot version 5.2 patch level 7.

Thank you,
-Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be triggered by a combination of non-blank title and plot style xyerrorlines.  I don't think the setting of errorbar properties per se affects this.  I will look into the underlying cause of the bug, but meanwhile here is a work-around:

```
$D1 << EOD
1   1   0.1 0.5
2   4   0.1 0.5
3   9   0.1 0.5
4   16  0.1 0.5
EOD
$D2 << EOD
1   2   0.1 0.5
2   6   0.1 0.5
3   11  0.1 0.5
4   18  0.1 0.5
EOD

set errorbars 5 linewidth 2 dashtype 1
plot $D1 with xyerrorlines lc rgbcolor "#B2B2B2" pt 2 ps 4 lw 4 dt 3 notitle,\
     $D2 with xyerrorlines lc rgbcolor "#000000" pt 2 ps 2 lw 4 dt 4 notitle, \
keyentry with xyerrorlines lc rgbcolor "#B2B2B2" pt 2 ps 4 lw 4 dt 3 title "Method 1",\
keyentry with xyerrorlines lc rgbcolor "#000000" pt 2 ps 2 lw 4 dt 4 title "Method 2"
```

The trick is to first plot the desired data with no title so that the bug is avoided, then create corresponding key entries using a title but no data.  The "keyentry" plot component is relatively new but it is present in version 5.2.7.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting this workaround and for confirming this actually is odd behavior!  Should I submit this to Gnuplot as a bona fide bug?

Comment: Please do.  I'll look at it regardless but it helps to have a record on the issue tracker.

Comment: One issue with your workaround: notice the key entries don't have the correct dashtype.  It appears this title/errorbar conflict also infects keyentry.  Diabolical!

Comment: The key entry for any plot style that includes errorbars shows the linetype of the errorbar, not the linetype of the main plot.  That may not be what you expected it to show, but it is a separate issue from the bug you found. The good news is that you can use the same trick as before to switch what is shown in the key.  See amended answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, I get it - that the key mimics the errorbar style is a good default behavior. In the meantime, I like your workaround because it allows me to customize the key all the more. Thank you again.

Comment: Wow, you fixed it.  My first ever bug report.  I feel useful!